# Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 6 in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, webchromeclient

I am trying to run Selenium on Colab, but an error occurs. It ran well a few weeks ago, but an error occurred suddenly today at the last line of code. Please, what should I do?

```
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get("https://www.website.com")
print(wd.page_source)  # results
```

My error message below in google colab

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
%%shell
# Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
#
# Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-                        
install-chromium-without-snap

# Add debian buster
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg]             
http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg]             
http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg]     
http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian- 
buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian- 
buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian- 
security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500


Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF

# Install chromium and chromium-driver
apt-get update
apt-get install chromium chromium-driver

# Install selenium
pip install selenium
```

Then :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "http://example.com" 
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=options)

driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JGKX0IafYw00vwCiOWphUBDBSCWCw7GZ?usp=sharing